# How can I get a sum from two different columns in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following columns in a table called "match_scores":

```
player_1, player_2, player_1_points, player_2_points
tom, mike, 110, 40
tom, joe, 115, 30
mike, tom, 120, 30
```

I would like the result to be:

```
tom has 255 points
mike has 160 points
joe has 30 points
```

Comment: Are you at an early enough position in development that you can rearchitect the database? This seems to be requiring a lot of work for something that could be much easier done with a simple table of playerName, playerPosition (1 or 2), matchID, playerPoints. At that point, it would be trivial to get total points for your players. And then if you need to pull them back into a flattened form for individual match scores, you could create a view.

Comment: @Shawn, I am sure there are other "better" solutions, like creating another table just for points purposes, but the site has been up for 5 years and we do not have much resources to re architect it.  This was exactly what I was looking for and that query solved the problem we were having. Thanks for your input anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can "unpivot" the data and then re-aggregate.  In SQL, this looks like:

```
select player, sum(points) as points
from ((select player_1 as player, player_1_points as points from match_scores ms1) union all
      (select player_2 as player, player_2_points as points from match_scores ms2) 
     ) t
group by player;
```

This returns the data as a result set with two columns.  You can convert to a string in SQL, but I really recommend that you do that at the application layer.

Comment: this query returns the following error:
Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @Matt, removing ms1 and ms2 and adding "as t" right before "group by player"

Comment: @TomW . . . The outer query needed an alias.

Answer (score 1):

This is the query that resolved the issue:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (player), sum(points)
FROM (
       SELECT player_1 AS player, player_1_points AS points FROM match_scores
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT player_2 AS player, player_2_points AS points FROM match_scores
     ) AS t
GROUP BY player
```

so the placement of alias as you notice is right at the end, and only one. For some reason the placement of aliases at end of each select still caused the error

Comment: *For some reason the placement of aliases...* Right, because the alias is for the *derived* query, not the statements within it.  Side note, since the query aggregates by "player", the `DISTINCT` is redundant. You can remove it.

Comment: You probably won't notice much of a performance impact with just a few records, but when you get more matches, I'm not sure that a sub-query method will be as quick as a PIVOT. Though the above query is simple to read and understand. And to get the data that you need might require some gymnastics with a PIVOT, possibly negating any performance gain. But I still stand by my original suggestion above of making this table simpler to consume.

Comment: @Leigh. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This should work..

```
select player, sum(points) as points
from (select player_1 as player, player_1_points as points 
      from match_scores 
      union all
      select player_2 as player, player_2_points as points 
      from match_scores) as a
group by player;
```

Comment: Almost. You just need to alias the derived table.